# Drawing custom route

Tags: android, google-maps, routes, map-directions

i am developing app for people who are travelling across countries, and also when they travel, they can bring up their pet to give someone to keep their pet for some time (pet adoption app, and will be used for adoption organizations , so they can organize themselves more efficiently in trips).

And user needs to specify in map, where exactly he is going (to mark with red marker in maps, where he is going).
So my app automatically create route for him (like in google maps, there are two of them, which he can choose).
**But** that is still just google prediction and suggestion.
Maybe user will travel across whole europe to just to go in London. So he should have option to draw him own route where he will go.

But i dont know how to do following:

1. Make route from his starting point to end point (from his location, to marker)
2. Make custom route (so he can draw his route from his location to marker)
3. And i dont know how to store route in database. I will use MySQL, and i dont know how to store route instance, so other users can see which route he choosed.
4. And also, i dont know how to store marker instance in MySQL database, so other users can see.
5. And if option custom route, how i can make UI to tell user, that he can draw his route. With what tools?

Sorry if duplicate, but drawing custom route isn't duplicate.
I would much appreciate to be answered to all 5 questions, even if some of them have answer (send me link to where).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this using Google MyMaps service.

https://www.google.com/maps/about/mymaps/